# Abstract type member of a singleton object

Tags: scala, singleton, overriding, type-alias, abstract-type

Abstract member method is illegal in a singleton object

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   def g: Int
     | }
         def g: Int
             ^
On line 2: error: only traits and abstract classes can have declared but undefined members
```

as is abstract value member

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   val x: Int
     | }
         val x: Int
             ^
On line 2: error: only traits and abstract classes can have declared but undefined members
```

however *abstract type member* is legal in a singleton object

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   type A
     | }
object Foo
```

so clearly the sense in which a type member is abstract is different from other abstract members. What is the difference? How can an abstract type member be useful when it seems it cannot be made concrete since object is final?

Comment: There was a discussion about this in the contributors' channel, you can search for that. There are reasons for this, but I really did not understand them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  Do you mean [What’s in a type alias](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/whats-in-a-type-alias/4001)? Seems it is not abstract from what I can gather.

Comment: I believe it was this [one](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/uninitialized-abstract-types/4146) but I do not remember if this one the only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the things is `type` doesn't have to be concrete. You can write:

```
type Arbitrary
```

in Ammonite and it compiles and runs. You can even use it as argument!

```
type Arbitrary

def foo(a: Arbitrary): List[Arbitrary] = List(a)
```

The only issue is, that compiler doesn't know anything about `Arbitrary` (e.g. that it `<: String` or something) which would allow you to legally create a value of this type.

From that point of view, abstract type member is just a type we don't know anything about, but which we can around knowing only that it exist and value would be of this type.

But, we can also `override` this empty definition by making it more specific e.g.

```
type Arbitrary = String
type Arbitrary <: AnyVal
type Arbitrary >: User
```

Then whoever implements it will have access to full type information, while programmer writing code that has abstract definition in scope can only pass type around.

Accidentally, that's how we rediscovered path-dependent types, or rather figured out that being able to create abstract types is kind of necessary if we want to have path-dependent types without manually maintained list of cases where we don't want them.

In Cats in Scala 2 this has another use case. There is a pattern which apparently was discovered by [Edward Kmett](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/2553#issuecomment-493626298) that uses abstract type member and `.asInstanceOf` to workaround missing polymorphic functions that we could lift to a type class:

```
trait DoubleSize[F[_]] {
  def double[A](fa: F[A]): F[A]
}
object DoubleSize {

  type Arbitrary
  def instance[F[_]](fun: F[Arbitrary] => F[Arbitrary]): DoubleSize[F] = new DoubleSize[F] {
    def double[A](fa: F[A]): F[A] = fun(fa.asInstanceOf[F[Arbitrary]]).asInstanceOf[F[A]]
  }

  // in Dotty we could do
  // def instance[F[_]](fun: [A] => F[A] => F[A]) = new DoubleSize[F] {
  //    def double[A](fa: F[A]): F[A] = fun[A](fa)
  // }
  // but in Scala 2 it's impossible
}

val doubleSize = DoubleSize.instance[List] { list =>
  list ++ list
}

doubleSize.double(List(1,2,3))
doubleSize.double(List("a", "b", "c"))
```

This kind of workarounds wouldn't be possible if we ruled out abstract type members, though in Dotty this particular workaround won't be necessary anymore.

Comment: This seems to work without `type Arbitrary` by just using existential `def instance[F[_]](fun: F[_] => F[_])`: [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JUryvZvNSbOVs8xq0Kntwg)

Comment: Yes, it's another way of implementing it, though if we think about it, it's the same concept, just one of them make things more explicit. And If you expand existential type, what do you see there? `X forSome { type X }` - empty type member, just defined in a different place.

Comment: @MarioGalic No, that doesn't work. Try adding `DoubleSize.instance[List] { list => List(42) }.double(List("x")).head.size` to your scastie snippet. It will happily compile, but then crash with a classcastexception.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@tpolecat](https://gitter.im/scala/scala?at=5a2f224bcc1d527f6b1d9c01) and [Dmytro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62475911/5205022) it seems abstract type member is related to an existential type

```
scala> object O {
     |   type A
     |   implicitly[A <:< (x forSome { type x })]
     | }
object O
```