# Difference between an undefined abstract type member and an existential type

Tags: scala, types, equivalent, existential-type, type-alias

Given an uninitialised abstract type member is `=:=` equal to an existential type

```
implicitly[Undefined =:= x forSome { type x }]   // ok
```

then why there seems to be a difference between them in

```
object O {
  type Undefined

  implicitly[Undefined =:= _]   // ok

  def g[F[_]](fun: F[_] => F[_]) = ???
  def h[F[_]](fun: F[Undefined] => F[Undefined]) = ???

  g[List](l => List(42))   // ok
  h[List](l => List(42))   // error
}
```

Note how `g` compiles whilst `h` raises type mismatch error. Furthermore consider

```
object O {
  type Undefined
  type Existential = x forSome { type x }

  implicitly[Undefined =:= x forSome { type x }]   // ok
  implicitly[Undefined =:= Existential]            // error
}
```

If `Undefined` equals `x forSome { type x }`, and `x forSome { type x }` equals `Existential`, then why does `Undefined` not equal `Existential`?

Comment: @DmytroMitin What is the meaning of `implicitly[Undefined =:= _]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed brackets:

```
implicitly[Undefined =:= (x forSome { type x })]
```

So it doesn't compile.

There should be difference between them. They are different.

```
implicitly[Undefined <:< (x forSome { type x })]
```

but not vice versa.

Actually `x forSome { type x }` is just `Any`.

> What is the meaning of `implicitly[Undefined =:= _]`?

`implicitly[Undefined =:= _]` is `implicitly[(Undefined =:= x) forSome {type x}]`.

And `Undefined =:= x` is true for some `x`. Namely for `Undefined`.