# Why is it possible to define a class with a unreified path-dependent type?

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type, abstract-type

Considering the following example:

```
trait Supe {

  type Out <: Supe
  def out: Out
}

class Reif1 extends Supe {

  type Out = Reif1
  override def out: Out = this
}

class Reif2 extends Supe {

  type Out >: this.type <: Reif2
  override def out: Out = this
}
```

`class Reif1` should obviously work. as `type Out` is reified and becomes a type alias

`class Reif2` also works but seriously? `type Out` only has upper/lower bound defined and the bound was not even tight enough: `this.type` is a singleton type, and `Reif2` is a class type. So what exactly would `Out` look like if `Reif2` got instantiated? Is it going to be `this.type`? Or `Reif2`? But the bigger question should be: why scalac 2.12/2.13 allows it be compiled?

Comment: The language allow abstract types in non abstract classes. It is actually a feature, since there are some advanced use cases that require the type to be abstract. - sadly, there is no way to force subclasses to implicit it, except putting a middle class / trait that uses a type parameter instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala (or in DOT calculus [1](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/215280) [2](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/02/03/essence-of-scala.html)) all types are intervals.

`type Out = Reif1` is (or is supposed to be) `type Out >: Reif1 <: Reif1`.

Abstract type without bounds `type Out` is `type Out >: Nothing <: Any`.

> So what exactly would `Out` look like if `Reif2` got instantiated?

It will remain exactly `type Out >: this.type <: Reif2`

```
val r = new Reif2

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
typeOf[r.Out] // App.r.Out
showRaw(typeOf[r.Out]) // TypeRef(SingleType(ThisType(App), TermName("r")), TypeName("Out"), List())
typeOf[r.Out].typeSymbol.isAbstract // true
typeOf[r.Out].typeSymbol.typeSignature //  >: Reif2.this.type <: App.Reif2
```

If you replace `type Out >: this.type <: Reif2` in `Reif2` with `type Out = this.type` (or `type Out = Reif2` or `type Out = Supe`) then `isAbstract` will return `false`.

[Abstract type member of a singleton object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457094/abstract-type-member-of-a-singleton-object) (see application of abstract type)

[What is the meaning of a type declaration without definition in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137522/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-type-declaration-without-definition-in-an-object) (see why it's not easy to check that `type T >: L <: U` is not abstract)

[Concrete classes can have abstract type members #1753](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/1753)

[SI-8217 allow abstract type members in objects #4024](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4024)

[Abstract type members are incorrectly forbidden in objects (unless inherited) #8217](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8217)

[Use of abstract type in a concrete class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274533/use-of-abstract-type-in-a-concrete-class)

[Concrete classes with abstract type members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115678/concrete-classes-with-abstract-type-members)

[What's different between "def apply[T](c:T)" and "type T;def apply(c:T)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148665/whats-different-between-def-applytct-and-type-tdef-applyct)

Comment: Wow, if that is true it will open a lot of possibilities
Once immediate observation is that TypeTag cannot be generated from such interval, I guess pre-dotty still had some obsolete paradigms that are hard to remove

Comment: @tribbloid *TypeTag cannot be generated from such interval* I'm afraid I don't understand what this means. `typeTag[r.Out]` compiles.

Comment: That's not what I mean, `typeTag[Reif1#Out]` compiles but `typeTag[Reif2#Out]` doesn't. I'm not sure about how it works internally, but I think in this case `r.Out` can be considered an existential type, not an interval any more

Comment: @tribbloid Yeah, for `Reif2#Out` `WeakTypeTag` should be used: `weakTypeTag[Reif2#Out]`. Existential is wider: `type Exist = r0.Out forSome {val r0: Reif2}` `implicitly[r.Out <:< Exist]` `implicitly[Exist <:< Reif2#Out]`. It's an interval but path-dependent: `typeOf[r.Out].typeSymbol.typeSignature =:= typeOf[r1.Out].typeSymbol.typeSignature` returns `true` while `typeOf[r.Out] =:= typeOf[r1.Out]` returns `false`.

Comment: @tribbloid `typeOf[r.Out].typeSymbol.typeSignature =:= internal.typeBounds(internal.thisType(typeOf[Reif2].typeSymbol), typeOf[Reif2])` returns `true`.